# How to save colour (color) ramps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, color, color-ramp

This strikes me that it should be simple, but efforts in QGIS and research here and elsewhere are not providing a solution.

I have a (vector) map which I have to mark out in colours according to the values of the individual sectors.  To aid the maps use for those with colour blindness issues I am only using one colour - blue.  The colours in the standard colour ramp are too close so I have made my own thus: -

New Colour Ramp
Gradient - OK
Colour 1 - white
Colour 2 - blue
Name the Colour Ramp - Test - OK

I have now got 5 colours in front of me.  Only the White is acceptable, so I double click on each colour in turn and change their values to make them more widely spaced - OK - OK.

When I print out the map all is well, but when I save that project, then open another and try to apply the colour ramp the colours have gone back to the default values in that colour ramp.  I have messed about in the style manager with no success.  Will I have to manually set all of the values for this colour ramp in each project that I wish to apply this colour ramp to?  Surely not!  There must be a simpler way.

Comment: Have you saved the colours as a style?

Comment: Gerald.  You are absolutely right.  I answered my own question before I saw your response.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

Ok I think from your question that what you need to do is create a style which can be applied to the same data set for the same colour ramp.  Assuming this is what you have meant.

For example, take rock classification from the British Geological Society.  Once you have classified each rock type into a relevant colour. Open the layer properties by clicking on the layer and selecting properties. Then on the style tab select save style. You will create a style for this layer.

So in your new project add the layer open the layer properties and click load style.

I think this is what you are looking for....if not i will delete the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Found it - so obvious!

Save Style and Load Style sorts

Comment: Doh. Was just typing answer when you did it. oh well there for anyones future reference.